# Drive SDK query results sorted randomly

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I have the following problem with Google Drive SDK.

Until some days ago the query results were sorted "last modified". Now it seems that I receive the results randomly and I can't use this SDK any more... I have over 400k documents and I really need the to be retrieved by newest first. When I migrated from DocumentList API to Drive SDk I was assured that this is how the results will be sorted (even if we don't have the possibility in SDK to set a specific sort).

Is there a way to receive the results sorted (by last modified)? Some weeks ago I have reported a bug on Drive UI because their UI sorting by last modified was not working ... maybe this two are related somehow ..

Example:
For this query (I have added q param - it works OK without it):
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=1000&fields=items(createdDate%2CmodifiedDate%2ClastViewedByMeDate)&access_token=[my_access_token]&q=fullText%20contains%20%27expert%27

I receive this results:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "createdDate": "2014-10-24T11:46:59.967Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-20T15:30:59.804Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-04-20T15:30:59.804Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-01T13:27:59.111Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-01T13:27:58.896Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-04-01T13:52:39.022Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-01T11:13:28.795Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-01T13:27:57.839Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-04-01T13:27:57.839Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2014-10-22T14:59:40.171Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-02-11T21:06:05.092Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2014-10-22T15:00:14.597Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2010-10-26T03:53:44.131Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-21T01:08:35.357Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-04-21T01:08:35.357Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2014-04-28T06:12:38.437Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2014-04-28T07:30:46.094Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2014-04-28T06:12:38.299Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2013-11-06T14:46:12.549Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2013-11-06T14:46:12.482Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2013-11-06T14:46:12.482Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2011-10-18T14:12:35.599Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-06-13T15:40:13.057Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2012-06-22T13:05:45.158Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-22T22:24:09.600Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-22T22:24:09.600Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2012-02-22T22:52:36.858Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2011-07-07T14:09:15.238Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2011-07-07T14:09:15.928Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2011-07-07T14:09:15.238Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-18T22:46:59.101Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-18T22:46:59.101Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-02T01:52:16.404Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-02T01:52:16.404Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-09T00:07:00.497Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-09T00:07:00.497Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-01T14:16:06.853Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-01T15:30:51.873Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-04-01T15:30:51.873Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-31T10:59:21.475Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-31T15:30:14.912Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-03-31T15:30:14.912Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-31T11:00:26.907Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-31T15:30:13.887Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-03-31T15:30:13.887Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-24T12:09:05.989Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-24T16:31:22.397Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-03-24T16:31:22.397Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-24T12:08:06.496Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-24T16:31:23.532Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-03-24T16:31:23.532Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-24T12:07:06.766Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-24T16:31:24.557Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-03-24T16:31:24.557Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-15T01:23:10.561Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-15T01:23:10.561Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-28T02:32:46.061Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-28T02:32:46.061Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-28T02:33:52.753Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-28T02:33:52.753Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-28T02:34:21.426Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-28T02:34:21.426Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-29T00:03:32.451Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-29T00:03:32.451Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-25T02:31:31.270Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-25T02:31:31.270Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2011-03-05T12:03:40.150Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2011-03-05T12:03:40.445Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-11T01:10:00.930Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-11T01:10:00.930Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-15T01:22:48.385Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-15T01:22:48.385Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-11T22:32:04.150Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-11T22:32:04.150Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-04T23:33:14.835Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-04T23:33:14.835Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-05-06T02:38:21.947Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2010-05-10T09:56:04.344Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2010-05-10T09:56:04.378Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-24T16:10:52.238Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-24T16:10:52.238Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2013-06-20T09:04:08.899Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2013-06-20T15:30:15.869Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2013-06-20T09:04:06.378Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-21T02:39:01.691Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-21T02:39:01.691Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-25T02:32:50.688Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-25T02:32:50.688Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-24T15:33:20.376Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-24T15:33:20.376Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-07T01:28:06.075Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-07T01:28:06.075Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-21T01:32:46.368Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-21T01:32:46.368Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-26T02:34:53.860Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-26T02:34:53.860Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-24T02:36:05.213Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-24T02:36:05.213Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-26T02:35:07.290Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-26T02:35:07.290Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-01T01:39:17.195Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-01T01:39:17.195Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-25T02:32:17.868Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-25T02:32:17.868Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-31T01:33:18.988Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-31T01:33:18.988Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-09T01:39:16.710Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-09T01:39:16.710Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-24T02:37:05.567Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-24T02:37:05.567Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-01T01:38:38.577Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-01T01:38:38.577Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-24T16:02:27.075Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-24T16:02:27.075Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-29T00:04:18.833Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-29T00:04:18.833Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-01T00:06:32.153Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-01T00:06:32.153Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-25T02:31:41.763Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-25T02:31:41.763Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2011-04-30T20:18:25.783Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2011-04-30T20:18:40.005Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2011-04-30T20:19:23.444Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-17T01:27:50.396Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-17T01:27:50.396Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-04T01:31:47.567Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-04T01:31:47.567Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-21T01:33:37.666Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-21T01:33:37.666Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-01T22:41:39.802Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-01T22:41:39.802Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2011-03-04T15:57:55.272Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2011-03-04T15:57:55.913Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-24T15:00:16.349Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-24T15:00:16.349Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-02T01:52:21.717Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-02T01:52:21.717Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-08T01:32:45.011Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-08T01:32:45.011Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-18T01:37:05.209Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-18T01:37:05.209Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-22T00:05:45.414Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-22T00:05:45.414Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-17T01:26:34.855Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-17T01:26:34.855Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-21T01:33:03.887Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-21T01:33:03.887Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-16T01:20:52.755Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-16T01:20:52.755Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-26T01:11:02.164Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-26T01:11:02.164Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-21T02:39:35.748Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-21T02:39:35.748Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-02T14:52:24.352Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-02T15:30:06.196Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2015-04-02T15:30:06.196Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-15T01:22:26.547Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-15T01:22:26.547Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-21T02:38:35.937Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-21T02:38:35.937Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-25T02:33:54.446Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-25T02:33:54.446Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-21T02:38:07.188Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-21T02:38:07.188Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-15T01:22:22.159Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-15T01:22:22.159Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-24T16:06:33.144Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-24T16:06:33.144Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-24T15:43:22.463Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-24T15:43:22.463Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-27T02:31:42.703Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-27T02:31:42.703Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-31T01:33:03.757Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-31T01:33:03.757Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-24T15:43:37.716Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-24T15:43:37.716Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-21T02:39:00.688Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-21T02:39:00.688Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-09T01:39:29.141Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-09T01:39:29.141Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-31T00:08:58.988Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-31T00:08:58.988Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-11T00:08:05.753Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-11T00:08:05.753Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-24T15:51:13.353Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-24T15:51:13.353Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-11-05T08:10:05.136Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-11-05T15:30:21.255Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2012-11-05T08:10:05.136Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-04T01:31:32.870Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-04T01:31:32.870Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-24T15:58:33.360Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-24T15:58:33.360Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-17T01:27:57.242Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-17T01:27:57.242Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-08T01:33:17.158Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-08T01:33:17.158Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-29T00:07:04.866Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-29T00:07:04.866Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-18T01:37:04.122Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-18T01:37:04.122Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-27T02:35:44.933Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-27T02:35:44.933Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-01T01:40:05.926Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-01T01:40:05.926Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-04-04T23:39:23.428Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-04-04T23:39:23.428Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-05-09T04:16:44.757Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2010-05-10T09:55:58.920Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2010-05-10T09:55:58.959Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2012-02-24T15:09:48.732Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-02-24T15:09:48.732Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2011-08-29T14:11:29.434Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2011-08-29T14:11:44.286Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2011-08-29T14:11:26.418Z"
  },
  {
   "createdDate": "2015-03-20T02:38:18.181Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2015-03-20T02:38:18.181Z"
  },
```

Am I the only one who has this big problem (on multiple accounts)?

Comment: Did you try orderBy last-modified in their API query?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this behavior. Can you post query/response samples of this behavior? Can you post code for your queries? As an example, what does this return: GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=1000&fields=items(createdDate%2CmodifiedDate%2ClastViewedByMeDate)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Comment: @Jayram, I don't have in Java SDK the possibility to sort the results, I didn't read anywhere about this option

Comment: @DanMcGrath, I will post soon the query/response sample in Java, and after that the HTTP requests...

Comment: @DanMcGrath, I have updated the question: as you can see the results are randomly returned

Comment: Thanks @AlexandruFarcas, I've filed a bug accordingly.

Comment: @DanMcGrath, how can I check the state of this bug? Do you know when it will be solved? It is very important for our application!

Comment: @DanMcGrath, any updates about this bug?

Comment: As per my answer, it's not currently being treated as a bug. When doing a full text search, it is returning it in order of relevancy. Any other order potentially puts the best matching answer at the bottom of a many million file list.

Comment: As Alexandru said, the default behavior until 2 weeks ago was that documents were sorted by "last modified". If now they sorted by relevance (default) that means that for a large number of documents some results may not appear. This has a big impact on our applications because some of us designed them when Document List API was available. So my question is: how can we sort the results ?

Comment: @DanMcGrath, the Google representative told us this:
"Currently there is no sort order that you can apply, and the order that is returned should be last modified. It's not always 100% accurate for reasons of distribution and recent changes, but it is pretty good." And now you told me that it was a bug? I hope that this is a joke and I didn't lost 2 years building an application on your Drive SDK platform

Comment: Alexandru & @Andrei F, feel free to reach out to me privately (see my Profile) if you want to give more information on how you are using this functionality. I've expanded by answer below to give you an alternative as well.

Answer (score 1):

## The Why

Since you are querying by full text, you are receiving the list of results in order of relevancy. When not using full text. This has been a long standing bug that was only recently resolved.

## What Now?

The API does not currently expose the ability for you to set sort orders, so there is not a method to have full text searches returned in last modified order.

### An Alternative

While the API does not currently expose a method sort by last modified date, you could issue multiple list queries using bounding dates. By walking down a list of dates, you could return the most recent results first, subsequently loading older matches as needed.

For example, after your full text search query term you could start by adding a filter for items that have been modified since in the last month:

- `modifiedDate >= '2015-04-06T00:00:00'`

If you need to, sort the results client side once you receive this set of results.

For subsequent questions, bound the results following this pattern:

- `modifiedDate < '2015-04-06T00:00:00' and modifiedDate >= '2015-03-06T00:00:00'`

Since you are bounding by modified date, this enables you to sort these smaller subsets independently, rather than having to wait for everything to arrive. You should scale the timeframe based on how many documents you are expecting it to return. Larger accounts might require daily or weekly timeframes.

## To Consider

Disclaimer: You will know your use case, so this might not be applicable to how you are using full text search.

Examine if/when you really want these search results returned in chronological order. For example, if a user searched for `May 2010 Budget`, documents that only contained 1 of those 3 words may be returned first, whereas the 2010 budget file maybe #10,000 in the list and never be seen by the user.

Comment: And how can I query to receive the results in order of "last modified"? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Until ~2 weeks ago, since the "start" of the Drive SDK, all full text queries were returned sorted by "last_modified", and I was told that this is the normal behaviour ... Is this a bug now or it is a change in the SDK?

It is a very important option for us, for my application ... without it I will renounce at sure at Google Drive ....

Comment: First: are you saying that if a user searches "may 2010 budget" the results  (documents) may not contain all the words? (you said "documents that only contained 1 of these words...").

     Second: the Drive UI has sorting options (when you search full text) so it seams to me that it is possible to sort, it's just not implemented in the Drive SDK (yet?). Am I right ?

Comment: 1) It depends on how you issue the query and we are always working to improve our search functionality. 2) This is not functionality available via the SDK at this time and there are technical reasons that prevent it.